# Replace initial loading spinner

Tags: vaadin

Is there a way to replace the loading spinner gif on the initial load?

[image]

I would like to have one customized to my app.

Comment: It's just an image in the theme. Take a look at the theme documentation. https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-overview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a gif included in the theme and yes, you can easily replace it. The spinner gif image is defined in the `.v-app-loading::before` CSS rule (well at least for the valo theme), you can actually override it for example this way:

Let's say we want to use gif `ring.gif` as a spinner imange and this gif is placed in your theme under `img` directory. This is the main scss of your theme called "mytheme.scss"

```
@import "../valo/valo";
// import other scss files here

// do valo variables customization here

@mixin mytheme {
  @include valo;
  // include other scss mixins here 

  // customized spinner
  .v-app-loading::before {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    background: url(img/ring.gif) no-repeat 50%;
  }
}
```

It's important to place `.v-app-loading::before` after `@include valo;`, otherwise it won't work...

More about theming here: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-overview.html